# deleting hibernate image after failed hibernation

Tags: hibernate

after trying

sudo pm-hibernate

my w520 can't start anymore.
only when adding a 'noresume' to the kernel parameters I can start with grup.

what are the steps to remove all the hibernate disaster?
formating swap partition?
what about fstab?

Comment: For me the same, hibernation stucks.
W520 running 14.04

Comment: As no one is butting in, have you tried deleting the swap partition/file?  :/  (just grasping at straws, but that is what I would do)

Comment: Converted my comment into an answer and added new info. If it solved your problem, please accept it to show the community that your question is solved (and to give us both a bit of reputation...).

Answer (score 1):

I would also try removing (unmounting), formatting and readding (as swap) the linux-hibernate partition using gparted. Performing this possibly makes editing a config file (/etc/fstab) necessary. You will have to re-add the partition to this list to have it auto-mounted at boot again. If you need more help (e.g. exact syntax needed in fstab or about use of gparted), please leave a quick comment at my answer.

Comment: the issue solved itself after some reboots with parameter noresume. don't know why.

Comment: But still a good answer, so an upvote!  ;-)